# Scala query need

Tags: scala

Hi I am getting an error with following piece of code.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._
import spark.implicits._


// Define case classe for input data
case class Article(articleId: Int, title: String, url: String, publisher: String,
                   category: String, storyId: String, hostname: String, timestamp: String)
// Read the input data
val articles = spark.read.
  schema(Encoders.product[Article].schema).
  option("delimiter", ",").
  csv("hdfs:///user/ashhall1616/bdc_data/t4/news-small.csv").
  as[Article]

articles.createOrReplaceTempView("articles")

val writeDf = spark.sql("""SELECT articles.storyId AS storyId1, articles.publisher AS publisher1 
FROM articles
GROUP BY storyId
ORDER BY publisher1 ASC""")
```

Error:

```
val writeDf = spark.sql("""SELECT articles.storyId AS storyId1, articles.publisher AS publisher1 
     | FROM articles
     | GROUP BY storyId
     | ORDER BY publisher1 ASC""")
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: expression 'articles.`publisher`' is neither present in the group by, nor is it an aggregate function. Add to group by or w
rap in first() (or first_value) if you don't care which value you get.;;
Sort [publisher1#36 ASC NULLS FIRST], true
+- Aggregate [storyId#13], [storyId#13 AS storyId1#35, publisher#11 AS publisher1#36]
   +- SubqueryAlias articles
      +- Relation[articleId#8,title#9,url#10,publisher#11,category#12,storyId#13,hostname#14,timestamp#15] csv
```

Data set looks like:

articleId   publisher   Category    storyId hostname

1   |  Los Angeles Times |  B | ddUyU0VZz0BRneMioxUPQVP6sIxvM  |  www.latimes.com

goal is to create a list of each story paired with each publisher that wrote at least one article for that story.

[ddUyU0VZz0BRneMioxUPQVP6sIxvM, Livemint]

[ddUyU0VZz0BRneMioxUPQVP6sIxvM, IFA Magazine]

[ddUyU0VZz0BRneMioxUPQVP6sIxvM, Moneynews]

[ddUyU0VZz0BRneMioxUPQVP6sIxvM, NASDAQ]

[dPhGU51DcrolUIMxbRm0InaHGA2XM, IFA Magazine]

[ddUyU0VZz0BRneMioxUPQVP6sIxvM, Los Angeles Times]

[dPhGU51DcrolUIMxbRm0InaHGA2XM, NASDAQ]

can someone suggest code improvement to get the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parser, compiler getting confused.

You have no AGGregate with the GROUP BY. Use DISTINCT on storyid, publisher.

Check if you also need storyId1 on GROUP BY as well.

Comment: Thanks it works with :                                                                                                           
 val writeDf = spark.sql("""SELECT DISTINCT articles.storyId AS storyId1, articles.publisher AS publisher1 
FROM articles""")
writeDf.write.mode("overwrite").csv("file:///home/user204943816622/t4_story_publishers.parquet")
writeDf.show(10)

Comment: Now if I want to further reduce the output by key 'storyId1' and count the number of occurrences. What shall I use?  I am trying code: val currCountDf = writeDf.count()
currCountDf.show(10) but this gives an error.

Comment: okay got it:    val currCountDf = writeDf.groupBy("storyId1").count().filter($"count" > 4)
println(""+currCountDf.show(10)+"")  but it show a round bracket at the end of the output (). Do you know why?